# Blutsauger without any Medic achievements?

Tags: achievements, team-fortress-2, tf2-medic

I just started playing TF2 and the only Medic-related achievement I have is Play Doctor. Yet, after only 2 hours of play, not all of which were as the Medic, I've already received the Blutsauger.

The official TF Wiki says this is awarded after 10 Medic achievements are completed (Medic Pack 1). Why do I already have it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Items can be found in-game based on the time spent in-game.  Currently there is no way to influence which items you find; it is completely random.  There is a limit to the number of items you can find per day, and the longer you spend not playing, the more frequently you'll find items for a while once you come back to the game.

Weapons like the Blutsauger can be found via achievement also for a couple reasons.  Valve set a precedent with that because the Medic pack and some others were released before the random drop system, and that was the only way to get the items at that time.  It is also because competitive players need access to all the items so that they can be on equal footing with each other, so there needs to be a way to reliably get a specific item.  At least, that was one of the reasons they added achievement-items back in the Sniper/Spy patch.  I don't believe they still think this, with some of the new items not added through large class patches.

Comment: All the Valve-created items have associated achievements, but none of the community-created items do.

Comment: I phrased my last comment badly:  All Valve-created items (3 per class) can be gotten by completing the milestone achievements.  There are also achievements that cannot be completed until you have those items.

Answer (score 1):

"Unique" character items can be either dropped or (some of them) earned through achievements, in your case it was dropped. The rate of the drop is based on the amount of time spent in the game.

Comment: When you say "dropped" does that mean it just is given to you? I don't recall literally picking anything up...

Comment: yes it's given to you by the system.

Answer (score 1):

That is when you finish the achievements. you can get it in a random item drop